# Different responses for glob in node interpreter and code

Tags: node.js, typescript, glob

I am getting different responses for the following two cases -

I am in the directory - dir1 and I am trying to glob for dir2

In interpreter:

```
const { glob } = require("glob")
let arr = await glob("/User/username/workspace/dir2/**/*.{feature,feature.md}", { ignore: ["**/node_modules/**"]}
console.log(arr.found)
```

The response is an array of strings:

```
[
  '/Users/username/workspace/dir2/src/package/to/name_of_the_file.feature'
]
```

However, if I do the same thing through code:

```
import { glob } from glob
let arr = await glob("/Users/username/workspace/dir2/**/*.{feature,feature.md}", { ignore: ["**/node_modules/**"] })
```

This gives the output with the node modules:

```
"paths": [
      /Users/username/workspace/dir2/src/package/to/name_of_the_file.feature,
      "/Users/username/workspace/dir2/src/package1/node_modules/@cucumber/gherkin-streams/testdata/good/minimal.feature",
      "/Users/username/workspace/dir2/src/package1/node_modules/@wdio/cli/build/templates/exampleFiles/cucumber/features/login.feature"
    ]
```

Is this expected?

I tried adding the whole path in ignore - `/Users/username/workspace/dir2/**/node_modules/**/*.{feature,feature.md}` and it still includes the .feature file under node_modules.

Am I doing something wrong? Do we need to pass another parameter?

Are ignore patterns relative to the directory in which they are run? If yes, how does this work fine in node interpreter and not in the code?